# How to declare and loop through a an Array of JSON objects in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angular

I have JSON objects that I'm getting dynamically using HTTP GET.

I want to save them in an array to loop them later and display them in the browser.

Please how to do that ?

Is there anyway to save JSON objects getting dynamically from URL in an array in Angular 4 ?

This is my model:

```
export interface IProduct {
    deferred_cmsg: number;
    unprocessed_cmsg: number;
    tempacked_cmsg: number;
    status: string;
    process_name: string;
    instance: number;   
}
```

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import {  
    Http,  
    HttpModule,
    Headers,  
    RequestOptions,  
    Response  
} from '@angular/http'; 
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';  
import 'rxjs/Rx'; //get everything from Rx    
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';  
import { IProduct } from "../models/iproduct"; 
@Injectable()  
export class ProcessJsonService {  
    constructor(private http: Http) {}  

   getProcesslist(): Observable < IProduct[] > {  
        return this.http.request('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpMCFgbCeW?indent=0')
        .map(res => { console.log("I SEE DATA HERE: ", res.json())
            return res.json(); })
        }
   }
```

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from "../models/iproduct";
import { Http } from '@angular/http';   
import { ProcessJsonService } from '../models/myjsonprocess';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {  
  pageTitle: string = 'Process List';
  imageWidth: number = 50;
  imageMargin: number = 2;
  showImage: boolean = false;
  listFilter: string = '';
  processList: IProduct[];  
  errorMessage: string;
  myProcessarray: any[];

  constructor(private _processJsonService: ProcessJsonService) {  
    this.processList = []; 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {  
        this._processJsonService.getProcesslist()
        .subscribe(processList => {
            if (processList instanceof Array) {
                this.processList = processList;
                console.log("souad", processList);
            } else {
                this.processList = [processList];
                console.log("souad aaa", processList);
            }
        });
          setTimeout(function(){
          location.reload();
        },60000);
  }           
}
```

and this is my html code:

```
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
  <div class='panel-heading'>
    {{pageTitle}}
  </div>
  <div class='panel-body'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-2'>Filter by:</div>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='listFilter' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <h4>Filtered by: {{listFilter}} </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='table'
                   *ngIf='processList && processList.length'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Process Name</th>
                        <th>Process Instance</th>
                        <th>Process Status</th>
                        <th>Temp-acked Messages Number</th>
                        <th>Unprocessed Messages Number</th>
                        <th>Deferred Messages Number</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let process of processList | processFilter:listFilter" >
                        <td>{{ process.process_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ process.instance  }}</td>
                        <td>{{ process.status }}</td>
                        <td>{{ process.tempacked_cmsg}}</td>
                           <td>{{ process.unprocessed_cmsg}}</td>
                        <td>{{ process.deferred_cmsg }}</td>  
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, how to get data refreshed if a new json is added in the URL (hhttp).

I used reload in the component but it's not getting refreshed. Also I used Async pipe in the ngFor in the html and it's showing errors.

Please any help on these issues ??

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue inside your service, you do not need the `return res.json()`. Update it as follows:

```
getProcesslist(): Observable < IProduct[] > {
    let url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpMCFgbCeW?indent=0';
    return this.http.request(url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Inside your component, declare your variable like so

`processList: IProduct[] = []`

```
ngOnInit(): void {  
    this._processJsonService.getProcesslist()
        .subscribe(processList => {
            this.processList = processList;
        });
}
```

There is also an issue with your html, you need to include `> 0`

`<table class='table' *ngIf='processList && processList.length > 0'>`

The above will work so that every time your page loads, it will fetch the list and store it for you.

To get the data periodically, you can do the following:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { TimerObservable } from "rxjs/observable/TimerObservable";

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    processList: IProduct[] = [];
    private alive: boolean;
    private interval: number

    constructor() {
        this.alive = true;
        this.interval = 10000;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        TimerObservable.create(0, this.interval)
          .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
          .subscribe(() => {
            this._processJsonService.getProcesslist()
              .subscribe((processList) => {                    
                  this.processList = processList;                                  
              });
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.alive = false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

To add a each new json list to the original list you would do the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    TimerObservable.create(0, this.interval)
      .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this._processJsonService.getProcesslist()
          .subscribe((processList) => {
            if (this.processList.length === 0) {
                this.processList = processList;
            } else {
                processList.forEach((item) => { 
                    this.processList.push(item);
                });
            } 
          });
    });
}
```

This will add each new `processList` to the original array

Comment: yes now my data are refreshed in the browser and I'm getting the new json properties but not able yet to get the previous json objects shown in the browser only the current json object is displayed. Please, do you have any idea how to get the list of all the JSON objects in the browser ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get the list of all the JSON objects in the browser"?

Comment: I'm using http get to load dynamically json objects means each moment I have a new JSON object. actually with my current code I'm displaying these JSON objects in the browser but at each moment I have only one row. I'm losing the old JSON objects when a new one is added to the URL. I want to save All the Json objects, display them in the browser and  means having dynaming list of objects in the browser. Di you get me ?

Comment: so you're wanting to constantly build onto 1 list? So the first time it fires it'll return 4, then next time it'll return 8, so total on the page must be 12 results after the second fetch?

Comment: For example each second I have a new JSON object in my http URL. I want to load it, save it and then add it to the list of json objects in my interface. Means I need to add each new JSON object to my browser (interface) without losing the old objects. I think when refreshing the browser, the array JSON objects is renitialized and I'm losing my existing JSON objects. is it ?

Comment: The page reload will rest the variable yes. I've updated my answer.

Comment: it's showing this error in ngOnInit when using push.   [ts] Argument of type 'IProduct[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IProduct'. Property 'deferred_cmsg' is missing in type 'IProduct[]'.'

Comment: thank you @Wesley Coetzee for your efforts. I'm getting another error "ERROR TypeError: oldProcessList.concat is not a function" I think this is related to typescript lodash version. I updated it to 4.16.1 and then to 5.6.0 but still getting the error multiple times.

Comment: I updated my answer again. I think there is something strange going on with your response though